# jquery ajax response is html, but can't manipulate it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm basically trying to work on server response sent in html. I'd like to count a number of elements present in the DOM fragment sent back by the server.
Yet, when I do :

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/myAjaxUrl',
    type: "POST",
    data : params,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        var total = $(data).find('li').length;
        console.log(total);
    }
  });
```

my var total is 0. Firefbug displays correct html, and the fragment DOES contains `<li/>` elements.
Where am I being wrong ?? Oo ??

Here are the response headers sent :

```
Date    Tue, 03 May 2011 12:52:55 GMT
Server  Apache/2.0.64 (Unix) PHP/5.3.5 DAV/2
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5 
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache 
X-Robots-Tag    noindex,nofollow
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=99
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html
```

And part of the HTML answer:

```
<li >
    <div class="">
        <a class="lookVisu" href="" rel="noindex,nofollow">
            [...]
</li>
```

Comment: Does the fragment contain `<li>` elements? can you show the response code?

Comment: It sure does. It's meant to be injected in current DOM later on.

Comment: Can you share the sample html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.find` searches the *descendants* of the elements in your set.

Your HTML probably has `<li>` elements as the top level, so `.find` won't find them.

If so, you can use `.filter`, which searches the elements themselves, and not their descendants.

Alternatively, you can wrap the HTML in a dummy element to turn all of the elements into descendants.

Comment: What if I do something like $('li', data).length  ?

Comment: That turns into a call to `.find`; it won't help.